# Can a group with the same ID of a deleted group be created?

Tags: linux

Say that I have created a group that has an ID of `1000`, and this group has some files and directories associated with it, and then I deleted this group.

If I create a new group, can this new group also have a group ID of `1000`, and hence the files and directories that were associated with the old group are now associated with the new group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "yes". If an existing group currently has the given group ID then it will have all of the associations of that group ID -
 regardless of how that came to pass.

We can easily verify this fact ourselves as follows.

First create a group `group1` with group ID 1000:

```bsh
user@host:~$ groupadd group1 --gid 1000
```

Check the group entry for `group1`:

```bsh
user@host:~$ getent group group1

group1:x:1000:
```

Create a file `testfile` and set its group owner to `group1`:

```bsh
user@host:~$ touch /tmp/testfile

user@host:~$ chown user:group1 /tmp/testfile
```

Check the ownership on `testfile`:

```bsh
user@host:~$ ls -l /tmp/testfile 

-rw-r--r-- 1 user group1 0 Jan 1 00:00 /tmp/testfile
```

Now delete `group1` and create a new group `group2` with group ID 1000:

```bsh
user@host:~$ groupdel group1

user@host:~$ groupadd group2 --gid 1000
```

Check the group entry for `group2`:

```bsh
user@host:~$ getent group group2

group2:x:1000:
```

Check the ownership on `testfile`:

```
user@host:~$ ls -l /tmp/testfile

-rw-r--r-- 1 user group2 0 Jan 1 00:00 /tmp/testfile
```

Notice that the group owner for `testfile` now registers as `group2`. This is because the group name functions as a sort of alias for group ID, while the group ID is the primary identifier.